# Matrices in $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ with characteristic polynomial defined over a subring

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, matrices, invariant-theory

Let $R\subset\mathbb{C}$ be a subring, and let $A,B\in SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ be matrices such that $A,B,AB$ all have trace in $R$.

For which $R$ can we then deduce that $A,B$ are *simultaneously* conjugate to a pair of matrices in $SL(2,R)$?

In particular I'm wondering about $R = \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Q}$, or a general number field.

(Each of $A,B$ is conjugate to a matrix in $SL(2,R)$, see the comments.)

Comment: 2: never (unless $R=\mathbf{C}$): pick $t\notin R$, define $A=e_{12}(t)$ and $B=e_{21}(1)$; then $AB$ has trace $t+2$. So $A,B$ have characteristic polynomial  $(x-1)^2$ which is in $R[x]$, but $AB$ has trace $t+2$ so $A,B$ are not simultaneously conjugate into $SL_2(R)$.

Comment: 1: always: if $A$ is a scalar matrix (scalar $t$), its trace is $2t$ so $t$ has to be in the ring. If $A$ is not scalar, it's conjugated to its companion matrix, whose entries are $0,1$ or coefficients of the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: @YCor Sorry, what is $e_{12}(\cdots)$?

Comment: @YCor Hmm, so in my case I also know that $AB$ also has trace in $R$. Would that change the answer to (2)?

Comment: @YCor (my motivation is to see if the character variety of homorphisms $F_2\rightarrow SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ of commutator trace $k$ given by the equation $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - xyz-2 = k$, where $x,y,z$ are the traces of $A,B,AB$ respectively, is functorial in the ring of coefficients of $SL_2$)

Comment: $e_{ij}(t)=I_2+tE_{ij}$, where $(E_{ij})$ is the canonical basis of matrices.

Comment: Yes assuming that the trace of $AB$ is in $R$ changes the answer, then there's a positive result.

Comment: @YCor Ah great! Would you happen to know if the trace of $A,B,AB$ completely determines the pair $(A,B)$ up to conjugacy? Would you happen to know of a good reference for this?

Comment: The functions $tr(A)$, $tr(B)$, and $tr(AB)$ generate the ring of $GL_2$-invariant functions on $Hom(F_2, SL_2)$, so in that sense they completely determine the pair $(A,B)$ up to conjugacy. A good reference is the book by Brumfiel and Hilden, "SL_2 representations of finitely presented groups." They work over $\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb Z[1/2]$ for the whole book.

Comment: @PeterSamuelson that some polynomials generate the ring of invariant functions does not mean that they separate orbits (a trivial counterexample is: if $A$ is nilpotent, then this triple of traces does not separate $(A,A)$ to $(A,tA)$ although these pairs are not conjugate).

Comment: @YCor Right, when I wrote "in that sense" I was being lazy/imprecise, and should have said they distinguish closures of orbits.

Comment: @PeterSamuelson it does not distinguish closure of orbits. For instance the set of pairs of matrices of determinant 1 and with all traces of $A,B,AB$ equal to 2 is not the closure of a single orbit.